# Extract full function definitions

Tags: ksh

Given:

```
$ cat test.ksh
doit() {
    doi1() {
        echo doi1 "$@"
    }
    doi2() {
        echo doi2 "$@"
    }
    doi1 a
    doi2 b
}
doit
functions doit
typeset -f doit
```

Why do I get this output (doi2() and the last } are missing):

```
$ perl -e '$a=join("",<>);system("ksh","-c",$a)' test.ksh
doi1 a
doi2 b
doit() {
    doi1() {
        echo doi1 "$@"
    }
 {
        echo doi2 "$@"
    }
doit() {
    doi1() {
        echo doi1 "$@"
    }
 {
        echo doi2 "$@"
    }
```

and not this:

```
doi1 a
doi2 b
doit() {
    doi1() {
        echo doi1 "$@"
    }
    doi2() {
        echo doi2 "$@"
    }
    doi1 a
    doi2 b
}
doit() {
    doi1() {
        echo doi1 "$@"
    }
    doi2() {
        echo doi2 "$@"
    }
    doi1 a
    doi2 b
}
```

Is there any way I can tell ksh to leave the function names untouched and thus give me the full function definition?

```
$ ksh --version
  version         sh (AT&T Research) 93u+ 2012-08-01
```

Comment: FWIW, you'll get the same behaviour with `ksh93 -c "$(cat test.ksh)"`.

Comment: @Kusalananda Yes. That is an even simpler example.

Comment: Strange bug. It seems to be triggered by ksh not having a script name: `ksh <test.ksh` has the same effect. It's not due to having multiple function definitions: the display is cut off after the end of the definition of `doi1`, except for any other nested function definition.

Comment: Can I set a (fake) script name? Somewhat similar to `$0="myname"` in perl?